# How do I get my email sign up form to work while hosting static webpage on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, contact-form, email-validation

Like the title states - I'm trying to get my email collection form on my static webpage to work while hosting on AWS.

The HTML is:

```
<form id="email-submit" method="post">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row justify-content-end">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="call-action-content text-center">
                    <h2 class="call-title">Want early access?</h2>
                    <p class="text">Enter your email below to gain priority access and to receive updates on the official release.</p>
                    <div class="call-newsletter">
                        <i class="lni-envelope"></i>
                        <input type="email" id="email-input" placeholder="Email address">
                        <button type="submit" onClick="submitToAPI2(event)">Stay informed</button>
```

And the jquery/ajax I found on Amazon's documentation I'm using is:

```
function submitToAPI2(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var URL = "the api gateway";

        var reeamil = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
        if (!reeamil.test($("#email-input").val())) {
            alert ("Please enter a valid email address");
            return;
        }

   var email = $("#email-input").val();
   var data = {
      email : email
    };

   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url : "api gateway",
     dataType: "json",
     crossDomain: "true",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     data: JSON.stringify(data),


     success: function () {
       // clear form and show a success message
       alert("Successfull");
       document.getElementsById("email-submit").reset();
   location.reload();
     },
     error: function () {
       // show an error message
       alert("Error. Please try again");
     }});

     }
```

Any ideas on why it's not working?

Comment: Where are you hosting your website, S3? What error do you get?
`url : "api gateway"` is this a placeholder? If not you need to input the correct url to your API.

Comment: No, I have the correct URL actually in the function, but when I try to submit an email I get "Error. Please try again" - aka the function didn't work. So I was wondering code wise in the html perhaps as to why this function isn't working?

Comment: What are you actually calling lambda, EC2? And where are you storing the emails? I think the `error: function (err) ` should expose an error object or something. Try to `console.log` it.